# Cassandra service not running on EC2

Tags: cassandra

I installed cassandra on my EC2 instance.

When I tried this **"sudo service cassandra status"** commend, it gives the below result

[**Result for sudo service cassandra status commend**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgox1.png)

I have the below setup

Python = Python 2.7.18
Java = openjdk version "1.8.0_302"

At the same time **nodetool status** and **cqlsh** commends also not working.

Comment: For the future, please include error messages as text, and not as images.

Comment: Can you post the error messages from the `nodetool status` and `cqlsh` commands?  Also, are you running those commands from the EC2 instance or from your local?